# Nested child scroll/overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

[Here's the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fast-v0ckh?file=/index.html), as the code is too much to post here, given the nested elements.

I'd like to have:

- a horizontal scroll for the `.content` div.
- a vertical scroll just for the `.group-body` div.

I've tried everything and I can't get it to work.

This rule does make it "work", but I feel like it's not optimal.

```css
.body{
    height: 90vh;
}
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You're required to show your code _here_.

Comment: looks like you need to reset scrolls to .content : https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-pike-0i4kw?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That is not it. I want the groups to scroll vertically, not the content.

Comment: @isherwood Isn't it too much code?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem - https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-dawn-1n8b1.

It uses a flexbox instead of grid layout.

Note: The code in the link was fixed after a comment pointed out an issue. To fix the scrolling, I set the parent elements that contain the sidebar and the content to `overflow:hidden`, and set the parent element to `overflow:auto`, which allowed for the scroll bars to be contained in the content div.

Comment: No, that is not what I asked. Only the content on the right should scroll horizontally, and the groups should scroll inside vertically.

Comment: Fixed it - check it out again (same link).

Comment: You're required to put your solution _here_, in your answer.

Comment: Again, not what was asked. The vertical scroll should only be on `.group-body`, not the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `max-height` for `.group-body` and then `overflow-y` will work as expected.

See [**this fix**](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-chatelet-9exy6) in your code

Comment: That's not the point. The goal is to not determine a fixed height.